# PgAdmin connect to remote server

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am having trouble connecting with pgAdmin4 to a PostgreSQL database (version 9.5) running on Ubuntu 16.04. The connection times out when I attempt to connect. I think it is being refused/dropped at some point but am not sure where.

Here are the postgres config files

[pg_hba.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv2A4.png)

[postgresql.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dVCl.png)

The result of running `netstat -tulpen`:

[netstat -tulpen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f3ve.png)

The result of running `service postgresql status`:

[service postgresql status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6bPf.png)

result of running `ufw status`:

[ufw status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eudC9.png)

Error message from PgAdmin:

[connection error (pgAdmin)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a5ok.png)

Attempting to connect with telnet also failed, returning the following message:

`Could not open a connection to the host, on port 5432: Connect failed`

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem has been solved.

The Issue was related to a firewall layer external to the VM running the database. The external firewall was not set to allow TCP/IP connections over port 5432, but it was possible to connect via port 3306.

As I did not have access/permissions to the external firewall rules, I changed the port and have been using 3306 since. I have had no issues with this. I have also started using an ssh tunnel for connecting from outside the network.

This is the changes to the postgresql.conf file required:

[postgresql.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilb9S.png)